# What is the difference between `ID` and `Internal ID` for NetSuite records?

Tags: netsuite

According to the help pop up:

ID

> This field's value represents the script ID, used to identify this
>   record for scripting purposes. It is a text field.

Internal ID

> This field's value is a read-only system-generated unique identifier.
>   It is an integer field.

- Both fields seem to uniquely identity a record type.
- One is a string, one a integer.
- The string `ID` is used for searches and
  loading of records, but I've also seen `Internal ID` used when
  referring to a record type from a lists point of view.

Can anyone provide the reasoning behind having two identifiers and when to use one versus the other when scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major difference is that you (as the creator of a custom record or script) are in complete control of the text ID. You can establish patterns and best practices for defining these IDs, and it will make it very easy for developers to identify record types just by looking at the string ID. You have no control over the numeric ID. When looking at code, it is much easier for me to determine what records I am referring to if it looks like:

```
nlapiSearchRecord('customrecord_product', null, filters, columns);
nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', 'customscript_sl_orderservice', 'customdeploy_sl_orderservice')
```

as opposed to looking at:

```
nlapiSearchRecord(118, null, filters, columns);
nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', 13, 1)
```

I'm not even sure the second `nlapiSearchRecord` actually works, but I know that `nlapiResolveURL` can be written that way.

That said, if you simply let NetSuite generate the text ID, you'll end up with generic IDs like *customrecord1*, which I find no more useful than the numeric ID. It is a good practice to explicitly specify your own IDs.

Furthermore, the numeric ID *can* vary between environments (e.g. Sandbox could be different than Production, until a subsequent refresh occurs). If you are following good migration practices, then the text ID should never vary between environments, so your code would not have to make any kind of decision on which ID to use based on environment.

Rarely have I found myself referencing any record, whether native or custom, by its numeric ID; scripts are always using the text ID to reference a record type.

Comment: Do you know of any time where I would be forced, by suitescript, to use the numeric ID over the text version?

Comment: I do not know of any scenario where you would be *forced* to use the numeric ID. The only time I situation I can think of is if you were manually generating the URL for a Suitelet/RESTlet, without using `nlapiResolveURL`, but I also have no idea why you would need to do that.

I have never found a scenario where NetSuite did not allow me to use the string ID when referencing a record type.